# Get similar not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to list similar products on my products page.It's working but everytime get last products on my database.Sorry for bad english.Thanks.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "/index.php?do=catalog/ajax",
                data: "ref=getSimilar&productId={urun_id}",
                success: function(data) {
                    jQuery('.similarProduct .productsContent ul').html(data);
                    if(jQuery('.similarProduct li').length){
                        jQuery('.similarProduct .productsContent').carousel({
                            direction: "horizontal",
                            dispItems: 4,
                            loop: true,
                            pagination: false,
                            autoSlide: true,
                            autoSlideInterval: 3000,
                            animSpeed: 1000
                        });
                    } 
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Your English seems fine, your question is not. Youve told us what happens, but not what you expected to happen, or what you want to happen, or what errors (if any) you're getting. There is no way to answer this sensibly.

Comment: Hi.I want to get my similar product id and show on the product page.Example my clock category id numbers:13,14,15,16 if product have:15 similar product tab need show 16,14,13.İf its 101 need get 102,103,104.Thx for help.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try This

 <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function(){
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "/index.php?do=catalog/ajax",
                    data: "ref=getSimilar&productId={urun_id}",
                    success: function(data) {
                        jQuery('.similarProduct, .productsContent, ul').html(data);
                        if(jQuery('.similarProduct li').length>0){
                            jQuery('.similarProduct, .productsContent').carousel({
                                direction: "horizontal",
                                dispItems: 4,
                                loop: true,
                                pagination: false,
                                autoSlide: true,
                                autoSlideInterval: 3000,
                                animSpeed: 1000
                            });
                        } 
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: "Try this" without any description of what you've fixed or changed is of little use to anybody. I cant personally distinguish your code from the OP's.

Comment: @Jamiec. While using multiple class we have to use comma separated.            jQuery('.similarProduct, .productsContent, ul').html(data);  jQuery('.similarProduct li').length>0

Comment: but you dont know that is multiple classes as you have no clue what the OP's html looks like! The selector `.similarProduct .productsContent ul` probably describes an HTML hierarchy! This answer is pure guesswork and quite possibly wrong

Comment: My products is everywhere on my page.Productception.